# Will the directional derivatives for a symmetrical surface always be the same?

Tags: calculus, vectors, vector-analysis

Suppose I have a sphere x²+y²+z²=a². Now (I assume) that the directional derivatives in any direction will always be the same. Hence there will be a gradient but it will be same in all directions. 
Is this right to say this or am I totally wrong?

Comment: The "directional derivative" refers to the instantaneous rate of change of the outputs of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as we move in a chosen direction.  So in our case we'd be considering the half-sphere $f(x,y) = \sqrt{a^2 - x^2 - y^2 }$, Suppose you are standing on the "equator" of this sphere.  The directional derivative gets arbitrarily large as we approach a path that is orthogonal to the equator, whereas we can achieve a directional derivative of $0$ if we choose a path parallel to the equator (indeed, we stay at the same altitude as we walk along the equator).

Comment: Can I say directional derivatives gives the slope of the tangent with the surface at a point in a direction we choose  i.e tan of the an angle of the tangent made with the surface at that same point...?